# Animation during onClick() on ListView item

Tags: android, listview, animation

When I click on one of my ListView elements a TextView shows up (or disappears) and backgroud color of four components in my element changes.

My problem is that it happens very quick. Is there a way I can make this more smooth? Like animation or something.

my OnCLickListener class:

```
private class TextViewOnClick implements TextView.OnClickListener {

    private TextView answerView;
    private TextView questionView;
    private Button tickButton;
    private Button crossButton;

    public TextViewOnClick(TextView answerView, TextView questionView, Button tick, Button cross) {
        this.answerView = answerView;
        this.questionView = questionView;
        this.tickButton = tick;
        this.crossButton = cross;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(answerView.getVisibility() == TextView.GONE) {
            answerView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

            questionView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
            answerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
            tickButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
            crossButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
        }
        else {
            answerView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);

            questionView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            answerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            tickButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            crossButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The recyclerview is much better especially in regard to animations - better use recyclerview here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot animate the color changing to be slower, you can change the view disappearing/appearing to be slower.

Look at the `ViewPropertyAnimator` class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html

You would use it kind of like this:

```
    if(answerView.getVisibility() == TextView.GONE) {
        answerView.setAlpha(0);
        answerView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        answerView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(500).withEndAction(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                 questionView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
                 answerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
                 tickButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
                 crossButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A6E7FF"));
            }
        );
    }
    else { 
     ...//follow the template above
    }
```

What this does (step by step) is:

-sets the view to be visible, but with an alpha of 0. This makes the component visible to the app however not to the user.

-animates the view to make it visible to the user. `alpha(1)` means that this view will be completely opaque by the end of the animation, and `setDuration(500)` means the animation will take 500 ms (you can change this value of course).

-at the end of the animation, this uses `withEndAction` to change the color of your other views.